# How to route leased IPv4?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ipv4

What I want to do is rent a dedicated server, install centos on it and route a /24 ipv4 to it

I think it's cheaper than paying for hosting,
how would I go about that ?

Please note that i know nothing and any small detail will help

Comment: I suspect it won't be cheaper than paying for hosting.

Answer (score 1):

> how would I go about that ?

Use your favourite internet search engine to for hosting providers that will provide a suitable dedicated server for your needs.

Narrow down the field by asking the providers if they will be able to provide you with a /24. the provider will deal with routing the /24 to your server.

Rent (buy) the server.

Comment: Thank you, great straight forward answer, but for the sake of knowledge, if i'm to start my own vps cloud with 1 dedicated server and a /24,  i buy the server, i lease the ips , how to route them ? And can i lease ips and route them to a server on another country ?